# MainWindow not showing in walk library

Tags: go

I am trying to create a window using Go's `walk` library, I have read through their documentation and have followed their steps accordingly, however when running `go run main.go` nothing happens,

Here's my code

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/lxn/walk/declarative"
)

func main() {

    declarative.MainWindow{
        Title:   "FetchTest",
        MinSize: declarative.Size{600, 400},
        Layout:  declarative.VBox{},

        Children: []declarative.Widget{
            declarative.PushButton{
                Text: "GET DATA",
                OnClicked: func() {
                    return
                },
            },
        },
    }.Run()

}
```

I have tried to add print statements where necessary, like before running the main window to ensure that I have setup my GoLang environment correctly, the print statement showed in the terminal, however after that it stopped

Comment: Try `go run .` (if you must use `go run`!). Note that I'm assuming you have created/built the manifest etc. Your code runs fine for me (using `go run main.go` will not work because it will not process the `./syso` file).

Comment: @Brits I have built the manifest using `go mod init` and tried `go run .` but it still doesn't work

Comment: `go mod init` relates to go modules (so is worth doing but not relevant to my comment). How to create/build the manfest is covered in [the documentation for `lxn/walk`](https://github.com/lxn/walk/#create-manifest-testmanifest) (which you indicated you have followed). If you have not successfully run `rsrc -manifest test.manifest -o rsrc.syso` (i.e. you have the `.syso` file) then you will not be able to create a window (as `go run` creates the exe in a temp folder using a `x.exe.manifest` will not work). Ideally just use `go build`...